# $G$ be a non-nilpotent and supersoluble finite group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent and supersoluble finite group.

$G=Q\ltimes P$ and $|Q: C_{Q}(P)|=q$ is prime, Where $P$ is a group of prime order $p\neq q$.

$Q$ is noncyclic group of order $|Q|=q^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha >2$ and all maximal subgroup of $Q$ diffrent from $C_{Q}(P)$ are cyclic Then every $2$-maximal subgroup of $G$ permutes with all $3$-maximal subgroup of $G$.

I dont have idea ?  What i do? Maximal subgroup of $G$ is not clear for me.

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called $2$-maximal (or second maximal )in $G$ if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Comment: Is a "$2$-maximal subgroup of $G$" a maximal subgroup of $G$ that is a $2$-group?

Comment: Since $P$ is cyclic and $Q/C_Q(P)$ injects into $Aut(P)$, $q$ must divide $p-1$, so do you mean $p=3$ and $q=2$?

Comment: A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called 2-maximal (or second maximal )in $G$ if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Comment: @NickyHekster $Q=\langle x, y| x^{9}=y^{3}=1, x^{y}=x^{4}\rangle$ and $Z_{7}$ be a group of order $7$.
I know $\Omega_{1}(Q):=\Omega$ is an abelian group of order $9$. Since 
$Q/\Omega$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $Z_{3}$ of order $3$ of the automorphism group $Aut(Z_{7})$. we may form $G=Q\ltimes Z_{7}$. its type of this group and $p\neq 3$ and $q\neq 2$.

Comment: OK, clear, you should have defined what you meant by n-maximal, I was not familiar with it

Comment: I define, I writed in the comment.

Comment: I posted a solution to the duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441084/g-be-a-non-nilpotent-and-supersoluble-and-2-maximal-subgroup-of-g-permutes-wit/441187#441187