# $G$ be a non-nilpotent and supersoluble and 2-maximal subgroup of G permutes with all 3-maximal subgroup of G

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent and supersoluble finite group.

$G=Q\ltimes P$, Where $P$ is a  group of order $p^{2}$($p$ is prime), all maximal subgroups of $P$ are normal in $G$, $Q=\langle a\rangle$ is a cyclic $q$-group ($q\neq p$) of order $|Q|>q$ and $C_{Q}(P)=\langle a^{q} \rangle$  Then every $2$-maximal subgroup of $G$ permutes with all $3$-maximal subgroup of $G$.

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called $2$-maximal (or second maximal )in $G$ if $H$ is a maximal subgroup of some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I Want to show every 2-maximal subgroup of G permutes with all 3-maximal subgroup of G

Comment: Sorry, ignore my duplicate claim. I had apparently not read thoroughly enough.

Comment: Please note that the statement "all maximal subgroups of $P$ are normal in $G$" is redundant: $P$ has just one maximal subgroup $N$, which is then characteristic in $P \triangleleft G$, so $N$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point appears to be that every third maximal subgroup of $G$ is contained in $C = P Q^q = P \langle a^q \rangle$.

The reason is that if $T$ is a third maximal subgroup, its index must be divisible by $q$. So $q$ divides the index of $PT$. Now $G/P$ is isomorphic to $Q$, so by the [third isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem) $T \le PT \le P \langle a^q \rangle$, because $P \langle a^q \rangle/P$ is the only subgroup of index $q$ in $G/P$

Now $C$ is a cyclic normal subgroup of $G$, so every subgroup of $C$ is normal in $G$, and thus permutes with every other subgroup.

Comment: Why  C is a cyclic normal subgroup of G?

Comment: @EbruArdamoglo, $a^q$ is a central element of $G$, $P$ is cyclic and normal in $G$, $\gcd(\lvert P \rvert, \lvert Q \rvert)=1$, so $C = P\langle a^q \rangle \cong P\times \langle a^q \rangle$ is cyclic, and normal in $G$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: if you are not psychic, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2536932 Theorem 3.5.4 -- 20 or 30 results and remarks in this paper are questions on this site.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti tank you for helpful Hint. Yes i read this article. I say you Jack Schmidt. Am i guilty?. In this article write clear but i cant proof.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, amazing, thanks!